# What is the speed of magnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-fields

I'm not a physicist (just have a few basic notions) and this is a question out of curiosity, so as I'll probably word it the simplest I can, please take that into account when answering.

**tl;dr**

Let's take an electromagnet, power it off and hang it over a table. Put a small metallic something below it, on the table. Power on the magnet and suppose for the sake of simplicity that the magnetic field form instantaneously. After how much time the metallic something will be attracted to the magnet? And at what speed it will move toward the magnet?

In the end, what is the speed of magnetism?

---

**Long version**

This is been a curiosity I've had for years about at which speed happens the interaction in magnetics fields. I know that $F=ma$, so I suppose that if a magnet is given with a certain F, the a of an attracted objects will depends by its mass (well, and the distance too decreasing F)

Then I saw years ago an experiment about it on Mythbusters, and then, yesterday, I remembered about Physics.se

In Mythbusters, they were trying to divert the trajectory of a bullet by shooting it over a long line of very powerful magnets. Well, the bullet was not impressed that much and never diverted a bit (visibly, at least). I can somehow realize that there are a lot of things at play, but still I fail to understand how a simple bullet exerciting a momentum of few kg can avoid the strength of a bunch of magnets capable of lifting 150kg. The only thing that came to my mind is that the bullet travel too fast for the magnetic field to interact with it, thus the question about the "speed of magnetism," but still this seems the wrong explanation to me, even.

Comment: The people who study physics are called physicists. Physicians are "doctors" who try to cure other people's diseases - to improve their physical health or condition.

Comment: 10x :-)

I'm Italian, so English is not exactly my first language ;-)

Comment: It's a frequent mistake here in Czechia, too. A few years ago, student leader from 1989 Šimon Pánek (now a charity guy) attended a conference of mathematicians and physicists in Prague and he has used "physicians" throughout his talk. I did tell him, too. "So people could see I didn't have a clue what I was talking about," he said. I didn't object. ;-)

Comment: Once, the magnetic field is stablished, interaction is instantaneous.

Comment: Assuming that by "instantaneous", you mean "permanent" effect of the magnetic field, right? If something exists permanently, one can't say how "quickly" it exists.

Comment: @LubošMotl: just to avoid confusion, I was talking about an electromagnet, so it is first powered off and then powered on. By the way...I'm not in the need to 'solve a problem or to have formulas or such. I'm just trying to understand how things works from a generic point of view.

Comment: It's hard to say exactly why the bullet was unaffected without the link to the experiment in question. For sure, in the appropriate arrangement I would expect the bullet to deviate considerably.

Comment: Though on second thoughts, bullets are usually made from non-ferromagnetic materials and shouldn't be considerably affected by magnetic fields. From what I googled, it seems, Mythbusters did not have a big enough array of magnets for the bullet to spend any appreciable amount of time in the magnetic field. Given that and that it's made of lead, not iron, it's not surprising, that it wasn't deflected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several time delays I can think of.

1. When you "turn on" an electromagnet, the current doesn't instantly go to its final value. The coil is an inductor, and inductors generate EMF that opposes changes in current. This doesn't affect the Mythbusters experiment because their magnets were already on.
2. The magnetic field itself forms at light speed following Maxwell's equations.
3. Magnetic forces on macroscopic objects depend on reactions of many electrons in the materials. Eddy currents (for a "drag" force) don't form instantly. Magnetic domains (for an attractive force) don't organize instantly.
4. The bullet's path changes if its momentum changes. Impulse is the change in momentum,  and it is force times time. The bullet passes by the magnets quickly so the force doesn't have much time to act.